# Holding the same binning in the train and test vector data sets

Tags: julia

I have a numeric vector `train` that I use in a training data set for a model. Assume I want to cut it into 5 bins. I know I can do it using `cut(x, 5)` from CategoricalArrays.jl. How to set the same binning in the `test` vector from a test data set of the model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps there is a better solution but this would work:

```
using CategoricalArrays, Statistics

nbins = 5
breaks = Statistics.quantile(train, (1:nbins-1)/nbins)

cat_train = cut(train, breaks;extend=true,labels=string.("BIN_",1:5))

cat_test =  cut(test, breaks;extend=true,labels=string.("BIN_",1:5))
```